# Show that the projection map $\pi :Y\oplus Z\to Y$ is bounded where X is a Banach space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a Banach space and $Y,Z$ are closed subspaces of $X$ with $X=Y\oplus Z$. Show that the projection map $\pi :X\to Y$ is bounded.

I do not know how to start to prove this. Can anyone give any hint?

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339892/are-projections-onto-closed-complemented-subspaces-of-a-topological-vector-space

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Instead of proving directly that $\pi$ is bounded, you may use a certain theorem that gives a more abstract criterion for the continuity of $\pi$.

(I'd be happy to be a bit more specific, but you specifically asked for a *hint*, not a complete solution. Let me know if this works for you!)