# Direct sum of topological vector space and the convergence of sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, topological-vector-spaces, direct-sum

Suppose $X$ is a topological vector space, $Y$ and $Z$ are two subspaces of $X$, and $X$ is the direct sum of $Y$ and $Z$, write $X=Y\oplus Z$. $\{x_n\}\subset X$ and $x_n=y_n+z_n$ where $y_n\in Y$ and $z_n\in Z$. Then if $x_n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, can it concludes that $y_n\rightarrow0$ and $z_n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

The $x_n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ here means $\forall U\in\mathbb{V}(0)$, i.e. $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$, $\exists N>0$, s.t. $\forall n>N$, $x_n\in U$. I guess the above conclusion is correct, but I can't proof it, and I can't find a counterexample either. It is obviously that if $X$ is a Banach space, it implies that the projection maps $P_Y$ and $P_Z$ are both continuous by Closed Graph Theorem, and the conclusion is proven out. However, in a Banach space, there defines a norm, and the convergence of a sequence can be defined by the norm. But a topological vector space can not always be normed. So what I'm thinking about here is a more general case.

Intuitively, the conclusion might be easy to be proved, but proving it is not so simple. May be it misses some conditions, such as "$X$ is locally convex" or "There is a norm or semi-norm on $X$"? I have no idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are projections onto closed complemented subspaces of a topological vector space always continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339892/are-projections-onto-closed-complemented-subspaces-of-a-topological-vector-space)

Comment: The proposed duplicate target *assumes* that the summands $Y,Z$ are closed subspaces, so it seems to me the present Question wants a deeper investigation of conditions that allow us to draw an effective conclusion about the "projection maps"  Voting not to close.  Perhaps someone can point out an implication I've missed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks!! It helps a lot!